# Python not displaying correct frame size

Tags: python, tkinter, size, frame, display

I try to figure out some frames to obtain something like that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/finae.png)

Problem is that the frame sizes are not displayed. Seems like sizes are not taken into account.
I missed something ?
Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os
img_dir=os.getcwd()
#Main window
root=Tk()
root.title('L-GEST')
#root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
root.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(1,weight=5)
#Screen dimensions
w,h=root.winfo_screenwidth(),root.winfo_screenheight()
w2, h2=int(0.8*w),int(0.8*h)
dimensions=str(w2)+"x"+str(h2)
largeur, hauteur=str(w),str(h)
#Resizing to 80%
root.geometry(dimensions)
#Top Frame
bandeau=Frame(root, borderwidth=1,relief=RIDGE)
bandeau.config(width=w2, height=100, bg='white')
bandeau.pack(side=TOP)
#Left side
Logo_path=img_dir+'/'+'logo.jpg'
Logo=Image.open(Logo_path)
Logo=Logo.resize((200,100),Image.ANTIALIAS)
Logo_load=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Logo)
Logo_label=Label(bandeau,image=Logo_load)
Logo_label.pack(side=LEFT)
#Middle
bandeau2_width=int(w2)-300
Button(bandeau, text="w2 ="+str(w2)+"w2-300 = "+str(bandeau2_width)).pack(fill='both', expand=True)
# Right side
Logo2_path=img_dir+'/'+'power.png'
Logo2=Image.open(Logo2_path)
Logo2=Logo2.resize((100,100),Image.ANTIALIAS)
Logo2_load=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Logo2)
Logo2_label=Label(bandeau,image=Logo2_load)
Logo2_label.pack(side=RIGHT)


#Bottom Frame
main=Frame(root, borderwidth=1,relief=RIDGE)
main.pack(fill='both', expand='YES')
Label(main, text='main').pack()
Label(main, text="main row 1").pack()
root.mainloop()
```

```
Could someone help ?
```

Comment: Please, review Your text before and after posting it. You might have a good question, but correct text formatting is important for others to understand it.  Make sure, that Image is displayed and don't use `Code block` for anything else but code.

Comment: Where are you trying to display frame sizes? Are you referring to the text on the Button? What is it displaying, and what do you expect it to display?